# Sinatra, ActiveRecord and ActiveSupport - Application could not be started

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, dreamhost, activesupport

This is a pretty simple Sinatra app that I'm trying to put on a production server. Locally, everything works swimmingly, but on a DreamHost server I am running into an issue. The error I see on starting the app is:

```
/valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:135: undefined (?...) sequence: /\b(?<!['\342\200\231`])[a-z]/
```

I've looked into the activesupport gem for any related open issues, rechecked that my local setup is similar to the server (i'm running rvm locally and not using rvm on the server if that helps) and still nothing.

Passenger is setup and I'm pretty certain the correct gems are getting hit since when I remove the activesupport gem I get a gem missing error.

I'm at a loss right now...

First the relevant bits of code:

GemFile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "thin"
gem "json"
gem "mysql2"
gem 'httparty'
gem 'activerecord'
```

app.rb

```
1: # encoding: utf-8
2: 
3: require 'sinatra'
4: require 'active_record'
5: require 'yaml'
...
```

config.ru

```
require ::File.join( ::File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app' )

run AppClass.new
```

My full 'gem list'

```
activemodel (4.1.0)
activerecord (4.1.0)
activesupport (4.1.0)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.6.2)
daemons (1.1.9)
eventmachine (1.0.3)
httparty (0.13.1)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
minitest (5.3.3, 4.3.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
mysql2 (0.3.15)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sinatra (1.4.5)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thin (1.6.2)
thread_safe (0.3.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
tzinfo (1.1.0)
```

And finally, the error via the Passenger "Ruby (Rack) application could not be started":

**Error message:**

```
/valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:135: undefined (?...) sequence: /\b(?<!['\342\200\231`])[a-z]/
```

**Exception class:**

```
SyntaxError
```

**Backtrace:**

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb  1   in `require'
1   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb  1   
2   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support.rb    25  in `require'
3   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support.rb    25  
4   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record.rb  24  in `require'
5   /valid_path/.gems/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record.rb  24  
6   ./app.rb    4   in `require'
7   ./app.rb    4   
8   config.ru   2   in `require'
9   config.ru   2   
10  /valid_path/.gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   55  in `instance_eval'
11  /valid_path/.gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb   55  in `initialize'
12  config.ru   1   in `new'
13  config.ru   1
```

Comment: You're getting a syntax error, which is not unlikely to be coming from the gems or server setup. Perhaps your Ruby versions are different on server vs local? Try adding `ruby "1.9.3"` (whatever your server's Ruby version is) to the top of the Gemfile, backup your `Gemfile.lock` and run Bundler again (and then reload/reenter the directory in terminal so RVM can load the correct Ruby version). This will give you exactly the same environments in both places, and if the error starts happening on your local, you'll know that the issue is in language version differences.

Comment: To add to @ArmanH's answer, the syntax error is mostly caused by pre 1.9.3 ruby versions and dreamhost by default uses 1.8.7 as per their wiki: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Ruby_on_Rails

Comment: Locally I am using RVM and have it set to use 2.0.0-p451 and have installed that version of Ruby on the server. When I run ruby -v on the server it returns 2.0.0-p451.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the **`sinatra-activerecord`** gem to add all the necessary activerecord rake tasks to my Sinatra apps. It also autodetects **database.yml** if it's in the **config** directory just like in a rails app. Try using the latest release, as it definitely works for Activerecord 4.1 now:

just change this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord'
```

to this and **`bundle`**:

```
gem 'activerecord', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '~> 2.0.1'
```

Then require it in your app by changing:

```
require "activerecord"
```

to this:

```
require "sinatra/activerecord"
```

And add this to your rake file to get the common Activerecord tasks:

```
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

You should now be able to **`bundle exec rake -T`** to see all the rake tasks available.